# Como montar lógica de ler 2 arquivos, compará-los e extrair valores não encontrados

Tags: java, lógica

Eu tenho 2 arquivos `.txt`, um deles é uma lista correta de cidades (contêm todas as cidades do país, escritas de maneira correta) e o outro, também uma lista de cidades mas com alguns dados errados (essa lista sofreu inserções do usuário, por isso tem erros de português, etc).

A fim de agilizar meu processo de correção da 2ª lista, pensei em verificar se cada cidade dela está inserida na 1ª lista (ou seja, **se estiver inserida quer dizer que a cidade está digitada corretamente**, **se não estiver**, eu **guardo essa cidade pois supostamente é um dado errado**).

Meu problema é a lógica, eu montei o seguinte código porém ele parece apenas percorrer a primeira linha do arquivo 2 (com dados errados). E também estou com dúvida em como usar a comparação, já que preciso saber todos os valores do arquivo 1 pra saber se a cidade que está no loop está no arquivo ou não.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aehoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner biCities = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\LISTA_CIDADES_BI.txt"));
        Scanner billCities = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\LISTA_CIDADES_BILL_ADDR.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Percorre a lista de cidades com dados errados
        while (billCities.hasNextLine()) {
            String cityBill = billCities.nextLine();

            // Percore a lista de cidades correta para cada linha da outra lista
            // A fim de verificar se cityBill está na lista
            while (biCities.hasNextLine()) {
                String cityBi = biCities.nextLine();

                // Problema de lógica de comparação aqui
            }
        }

        for (String s : array) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        biCities.close();
        billCities.close();
    }
}
```

As cidades estão representadas no padrão `CIDADE;ESTADO` conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
LISTA_CIDADES_BILL_ADDR                 LISTA_CIDADES_BI
(LISTA C/ DADOS ERRADOS)                (LISTA COM DADOS CORRETOS)
=- LAURO DE FREITAS;BA                  ABADIA DE GOIAS;GO
; VILAS DO ATLANTICO;BA                 ABADIA DOS DOURADOS;MG
ABADIA DE GOIAS;GO                      ABADIANIA;GO
ABADIA DOS DOURADOS;MG                  ABAETE;MG
ABADIANIA;GO                            ABAETETUBA;PA
ABAETE;MG                               ABAIARA;CE
ABAETE DOS MENDES;MG                    ABAIRA;BA
ABAETETUBA;PA                           ABARE;BA
ABAIARA;CE                              ABATIA;PR
ABAIBA;MG                               ABDON BATISTA;SC
```

---

Apenas pra motivo de informação, consegui montar uma lógica que funciona, ao invés de ler as listas cada vez em percorro o meu `while` eu salvei em 2 `array` e montei a condição abaixo:

```
ArrayList<Cidade> cidadesDiferentes = new ArrayList<Cidade>();

for (Cidade cidadeIncorreta : listaCidadesIncorretas) {
    int encontrou = 0;

    for (Cidade cidadeCorreta : listaCidadesCorretas) {
        if ((cidadeIncorreta.getCidade().equalsIgnoreCase(cidadeCorreta.getCidade())) && (cidadeIncorreta.getEstado().equalsIgnoreCase(cidadeCorreta.getEstado()))) {
            encontrou = 1;
        }
    }

    if (encontrou == 0) {
        cidadesDiferentes.add(cidadeIncorreta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Este processo tem de ser feito via código? Seria mais fácil e simples importar para um banco de dados e usar `select` e relacionando as tabelas.

Comment: Sim Jota, as 2 tabelas são de bases diferentes e eu não possuo mais acesso à base com os dados corretos.

Comment: Apenas para dar um toque. Com essa lógica você terá tempo quadrático em operações caras de leitura em disco. Se a lista de cidades não for muito grande vale mais a pena ler os dois arquivos uma única vez (cada um para um `Set`, e.g., `LinkedHashSet`). Para encontrar as entradas erradas basta fazer `setErrado.removeAll(setCorreto);`

Comment: O custo não é muito alto nem lendo em disco nem fazendo em memória porque temos só 5.500 municípios. Em memória entretanto é bem mais simples. Além disso esta não parece uma operação a ser feita 10 vezes ao dia, dá pra não se importar muito com o custo. Carregue cada arquivo em uma lista e vá aprimorando a lógica de comparação entre os itens das listas.

Comment: Isso, uma lista tem 5570 registros e a outra 8866, vou fazer esse processo apenas uma vez a fim de pegar a cidade com erro e verificá-la no banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pedidos segue um esboço mínimo da solução em memória com `Set`.

Ler um arquivo para um `Set`:

```
public Set<String> leMunicipios(Path path, int linhasParaPular, Charset charset) 
        throws IOException {
    final List<String> contents = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
    return new LinkedHashSet<>(contents.subList(linhasParaPular, contents.size()));
}
```

Listar erros:

```
final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
try {
    final Path pathMunicipios = Paths.get("C:\\LISTA_CIDADES_BILL_ADDR.txt");
    final Path pathGabarito = Paths.get("C:\\LISTA_CIDADES_BI.txt");
    final Set<String> municipios = leMunicipios(pathMunicipios, 4, charset);
    final Set<String> gabarito = leMunicipios(pathGabarito, 2, charset);
    municipios.removeAll(gabarito);
    municipios.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Se a ordem não é importante, você pode melhorar um pouco a performance substituindo o `LinkedHashSet`por um `HashSet` (não que isso venha a ser muito relevante nesse caso).

Answer (score 3):

Ele está percorrendo apenas uma vez porque o `Scanner` das cidades erradas chegou ao fim do arquivo. Você tem de reiniciá-lo.

Faça algo assim no primeiro `while`:

```
<Segundo While>
biCities.close();
biCities = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\LISTA_CIDADES_BI.txt"));
<fecha While>
```

Uma outra opção é usar o método `reset()` da classe `Scanner`, desse modo:

```
biCities.reset(); //Se você usar alguma das funções Scanner.useDelimiter(), Scanner.useLocale()
                  //ou Scanner.useRadix(), deve reutilizá-las.
```